# getting " No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one " when testing a react query component with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-query, testing-library

I'm getting this error when testing a component that uses react query custom hook:
**" No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one "**

this is my hook:

```
export default () => {
  const loginMutation = useMutation(
    async (payload: LoginDto) => {
      return await MembershipService.login(payload);
    },
    {
      onSuccess: ({ data }: AxiosResponse) => alert(data),
      onError: (error: AxiosError) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    }
  );

  const signupMutation = useMutation(
    async (payload: SignupDto) => {
      return await MembershipService.signup(payload);
    },
    {
      onSuccess: ({ data }: AxiosResponse) => alert(data),
      onError: (error: AxiosError) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    }
  );

  return {
    loginMutation,
    signupMutation,
  };
};
```

and here is my test:

```
test("should display required error", async () => {
    render(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Signup />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    );
    fireEvent.submit(screen.getByRole("button"));
    expect(await screen.findAllByRole("alert")).toHaveLength(5);
  });
```

As you can see, I already passed an instance of QueryClient class to wrapper component.
And also I'm using axios and axios-mock-adaptor to mocking requests.

Comment: similar question, maybe you could find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590195/no-queryclient-set-use-queryclientprovider-to-set-one

Comment: I got it while I was testing with jest and react-testing-library, and I did not have any issues during development or building

Comment: duplicate of this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694015/integrate-testing-for-react-query-with-testing-library/

you're also not showing where the queryClient is created, and how the Signup component uses it